# Raspberry Pi 2.8" TFT Add-on just displays white

Tags: pitft

I am running a Raspberry Pi 3 with the latest version on Raspian Jessie

> PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
>   NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
>   VERSION_ID="8"
>   VERSION="8 (jessie)"

I have just bought the following device:
[Raspberry PI 2.8 TFT Add-On V1.0](https://www.itead.cc/raspberry-pi-2-8-tft-add-on-v1-0.html)

I have the one that doesn't fit on the Raspberry Pi 3 - however I have been told it shouldn't be an issue.

I have followed the following instructions:
1. I ran raspi-config - and I was unable to expand the filesystem:

> │ Your partition layout is not currently supported by this │ 
>   │ tool. You are probably using NOOBS, in which case your   │ 
>   │ root filesystem is already expanded anyway.

I was also unable to find anything about a device tree under advanced options, but I enabled SPI even if it wasn't required

2. I added the following to the end of /boot/config.txt
   dtoverlay=hy28b,rotate=90
3. I ran this: sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup and set it up accordingly
4. I modified /boot/cmdline.txt so that it looks as follows:
   dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait fbcon=map:10

The screen is always just white when I reboot. It never displays anything more. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the most part I had the wrong device. I needed to follow the blog post here: [RASPBERRY PI 2.8 TFT ADD-ON V1.1 TOUCH FUNCTION REALIZING](https://www.itead.cc/blog/raspberry-pi-2-8-tft-add-on-touch-function)

Mainly what I did was:

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install xinput evtest tslib libts-bin
- Created a file called /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-fbdev.conf with the contents:

> ```
> Section "Device"  
>     Identifier "itdb28"
>     Driver "fbdev"
>     Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
> EndSection
> ```

Then run:

```
sudo modprobe fbtft_device name=itdb28 gpios=reset:14,dc:2,wr:3,cs:8,db00:17,db01:18,db02:27,db03:22,db04:23,db05:24,db06:25,db07:4 rotate=90 fps=50 
sudo startx &
```

As for the touch, I am not sure how to get that to work yet...